# Not found: Op type not registered 'CountExtremelyRandomStats'

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I am getting the following error while running bazel command in the docker container.

command ran :

`- bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/model_servers/tensorflow_model_server --port=9000 --model_name=rf_quora --model_base_path=/serving/rf_model &> rf_log &`

error:

> - Not found: Op type not registered 'CountExtremelyRandomStats' in binary running on 864822af1c6c. Make sure the Op and Kernel are
>     registered in the binary running in this process.

I tried my search with the following link but in vain.
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11847

I am trying to do inference using tensorflow tensorserving, but I am getting blocked by the above error.
Using Tensorflow 1.3 and using `tensor_forest` api present in `tf.contrib.tensor_forest_python`.

Can anyone help me with this error as it is blocking my testing.

Note:- I have successfully ran **tensorserving** inference for **mnist** and inception examples models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue got resolved after upgrading to latest tensorflow version i.e. from 1.3.0 to 1.4 version.

**Reference**:-
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14358

Answer (score 0):

According to this the op is not supported and you have to add it manually:
https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/278

**Edit:**
The answer to this query can be found here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14358

Simply if you're running TF 1.3 and using the TensorForest, you'll need to upgrade to to TF 1.4.

Also for anyone running the TensorForest manually i.e. not using the TensorForestEstimator, I found it best to simply use the estimator as there were issues with other ops once I upgraded to TF 1.4

Comment: Hi kekura Lloyd Musa , I tried the suggestion by updating the BUILD file in /serving/tensorflow/tensorflow/ path .                      
tf_cc_shared_object(
name = "libtensorflow.so",
linkopts = select({
"//tensorflow:darwin": [
"//tensorflow:windows": [],
"//tensorflow:windows_msvc": [],
........
}),
deps = [
"//tensorflow/contrib:contrib_kernels",
"//tensorflow/contrib:contrib_ops_op_lib",
"//tensorflow/c:c_api",
.........
],
) but I am getting the error. Could you suggest the answer with where exactly I need to include.

Comment: I was able to find the cc_binary at the bottom of the BUILD file. However it didn’t work. I’m going to try and see if there is a way to configure tensorflow_serving

Comment: Thank You Kekura Lloyd Musa for your comment. Ya please let me know if you find a way to resolve and also i'll also let you know if I find any.              I just want to know that your are adding the lines in the path /serving/tensorflow/tensorflow/BUILD file itself or any other path.

Comment: Yes. That’s where I added the lines. I followed the instructions to use branch r1.3 since we’re using tensorflow 1.3

Comment: @srikanth I added this edit so we can conclude this issue on here

Comment: Thanks @kekura, apart from the answer, your edit for using estimators for TensorForest also justifies, as there are issues with ops in tensorForest. Even I also moved to estimators for solving the tensorForest